# updating a value on a dictionary after looking in key for a letter which corresponds to a numerical value

Tags: python, dictionary

I've copied a section of my dictionary below, which shows the French word and its character count. I want to change the character count to a more accurate syllable count when saying the word aloud.

--

```
myDict = {
"lire": "4",
"l'art": "5",
"écrire": "6",
"écouter": "7",
"compter": "7" }
```

--

These are the values which have to be added to the len() count
e.g w is 1 character but in french is 'dou-ble v' which makes 3 syllables so 3 - 1 = 2

```
myDict2 = {
"w": "2",
"y": "2",
"'": "3",
"é": "4",
"è": "3",
"ê": "5",
"ç": "6",
"â": "5",
"à": "3",
" ": "1"}
```

--

I want to search the keys in the dictionary for any of the letters/special characters in the table I've made and then add the corresponding number(s) to the value in the dictionary.

--

So far, I'm stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. Just a little PSA: I'm a total beginner to python (fewer than 10 hours' experience kind of beginner). I'm trying to learn by doing so I've made this project. If it would be helpful to know more about the project as a whole then please let me know and I'll edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ints instead of strings for your dictionary values. However, you can use this:

```py
myDict = {
"lire": "4",
"l'art": "5",
"écrire": "6",
"écouter": "7",
"compter": "7" }

myDict2 = {
"w": "2",
"y": "2",
"'": "3",
"é": "4",
"è": "3",
"ê": "5",
"ç": "6",
"â": "5",
"à": "3",
" ": "1"}

for key, val in myDict.items():
    new_val = int(val)                           # get original value as int
    for letter in key:                           # iterate over the letters
        if letter in myDict2:                    # if the letter needs more syllables
            new_val += int(myDict2[letter]) - 1  # increase the count
    myDict[key] = str(new_val)                   # update the old value

print(myDict)
```

Or, if you want to go for a one-liner:

```py
myDict = {k: int(v) + sum([int(myDict2.get(l, 1))-1 for l in k]) for k, v in myDict.items()}
```

Output:

```py
{'lire': '4', 
"l'art": '7', 
'écrire': '9', 
'écouter': '10', 
'compter': '7'}
```